# jQuery Mobile loading message

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

When I linked jQuery Mobile to my page, some sort of loading message appeard in the bottom of the page and I can't get a rid of it. I've tried $.mobile.pageLoading(true) but it didn't work.

How should I remove it? I haven't printed it anywhere.

Comment: JQM will display a loading gif when it is loading up a JQM page.  This is probably what you are seeing.  Can we see your code, it will help us determine if you have your page setup correctly for JQM.

Comment: I had the same problem, after upgrading to jQuery 1.90 the message disappeared and the orange frame vanished too.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### The 1.4 loader documentation

The 1.4 documentation suggests interaction with the **[Loader](http://api.jquerymobile.com/loader/) widget**. The top of the page describes globally changing the option but it can be nuanced on a link-by-link basis. This may also work:

```
$( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.disabled = true;
});
```

Also, according to http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/loader/ and http://api.jquerymobile.com/loader/, you can hide the loading experience with the following code:

```
// As submitted by @Aras
$.mobile.loading( "hide" );
// (or presumably as submitted by @Pnct)
$.mobile.loading().hide();
```

### Option B - disable AJAX loading

Disabling AJAX loading will effectively remove the message.

If you don't want a page to benefit from loading in the background *and then showing*, you can make it load like 'normal' by specifying the `data-ajax='false'` on whatever anchor (`<a...>`) tag you don't want to see a loading message for. There's also a global setting you can use to make all links load 'normally'.

To disable globally (be sure to [read this page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html) to understand implications and their recommendations. The [new docs](http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/) may not have warnings):

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled=false;
```

### Option C - just hide it

If you want to use the 1.4 [Load Page](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.loadPage/) approach to load external pages, it has an option available for `showLoadMsg` which you can simply set to false.

The global option (available in earlier versions -- at least 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2 -- read about it [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html)) for just removing the message is:

```
$.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
```

The 1.2 and prior documentation says that if you set it to false, no loading message will be shown.

Comment: $.mobile.loadingMessage = false; WORKED! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 29):

I am using the latest version of JQuery Mobile (currently 1.4) and run into this problem. None of the solutions here worked for me and I think many of them have been deprecated. Here is what worked for me:

```
$.mobile.loading().hide();
```

`$.mobile.loading()` will give you the element and you can `hide` it or do whatever else you wish. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me as well.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, an annoying loading message and an orange frame. It was due to not adding the reference to the jquery style sheet.

Adding the reference in the header solved it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css">
```

Comment: This worked for me, and looks like the proper way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me too! I think this is the right way of avoid Loading message.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using the latest update (1.2.0) of jquerymobile
try this

```
$.mobile.loading( 'show', { theme: "b", text: "", textonly: false});
```

since it worked for me.

Comment: How did you get that?,specific link?

Answer (score 4):

Pnct's answer is closer to correct for JQM 1.2.0. However, the below would be more correct per the API document provided.

```
$.mobile.loading('hide');
```

Also ensure you have the stylesheet defined for the JQM structure at minimum in your HTML file. Otherwise it will look like the function does nothing.

Answer (score 4):

In my case (`jQueryMobile 1.4.5`) I just had to add this to my CSS, and this way I can avoid importing the whole jQueryMobile CSS file (I don't need it).

```
.ui-loader {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Careful with this; you may hide it with a style, but Google will still pick up on multiple `h1` elements on your page.

Answer (score 3):

By default, that message should be hidden. It is likely that you have not included the official jQuery Mobile stylesheet.

You shouldn't manually hide or disable the loading message through code.

The correct method should be to included the following stylesheet for jQuery Mobile 1.4.5:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.css">
```

This will solve various issues including blue outlines around selected elements in Chrome and orange outlines in Android.

In case this post gets outdated, the stylesheets for all versions can be found over here:
https://jquerymobile.com/download/

Answer (score 3):

Add this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ui-loader").hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use smth. like that to remove the message:

```
$('.ui-loader h1').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg()`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was loading wrong css file (jquery css instead of jquery mobile css)

Wrong:

```
<link href="../CSS/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Right:

```
<link href="../CSS/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```