# Disable jQuery Mobile Loading Message and AJAX

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the regular jQuery library attached and the jQuery mobile file attached after (jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js).

As soon as I attach jQuery mobile and refresh the page, I get the loading screen.

I have tried disabling it with:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled=false;
    $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
});
```

As well as trying a different init function:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit'){
```

But neither have worked. I still just get the loading message or a completely blank screen.

The only function I really need it for is the swipe event.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Mobileinit** must be used before jQM js file is leaded, like this:

```
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled=false;
        $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
    });            
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
```

It won't work if you execute it after the script loads.

Comment: Just to say.. There is no src to the jquery.js cdn, which needs to be before the mobileinit AND anyways didn-t solve the problem, may be deprecated...

Comment: is there any way to alter the `$.mobile.` option after initializing jquery-mobile js?

Answer (score 2):

I have used CSS method. Not nicest but works and fast.

```
<style>
.ui-loader 
{
  display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

This question already answered: [jQuery Mobile loading message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397940/jquery-mobile-loading-message)