# jQuery Mobile - Auto loading text cannot be removed

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
});            
</script>
<script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But its still appearing, am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Mobile loading message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397940/jquery-mobile-loading-message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the sequence, **Load jQuery first**

```
<script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
});            
</script>
```

Comment: Same problem, loading is still appearing

Comment: Ow.. found the problem, I was specifying that after the custom scripts. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
 });            
</script>
**<script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/scripts/CUSTOMSCRIPT.js" type="text/javascript"></script>**
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of including all the mobile css just include the one with structure in the name: `jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.css`